# Custom Listview Loops through all images in first listItem

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-adapter, android-bitmap

i have a list view that is populated from a database with a customlistview...everything works fine except when i first start activity, the first item on the list view, loops through all images and then sets each image to corresponding item. I cannot figure out what i am doing wrong. pls help. I have gone through al the answers on stackoverflow but nothing works for me. Here is my custom list view:

***Edit:This code is working fine now. I fixed it.

```
public class FriendsListView extends ArrayAdapter<FriendsRowItem> {
Context context;
ArrayList<FriendsRowItem> infoList;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;

public FriendsListView(Context context, int resourceId,
        ArrayList<FriendsRowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resourceId;
    infoList = items;
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
}

public int getCount() {
    return infoList.size();
}

public RowItem getItem(RowItem position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (vi == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_3, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title3);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.icon3);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtTitle.setText(infoList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageView).execute(infoList.get(position)
            .getImage());

    return vi;
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    int position;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage, int position) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
        this.position = position;
        bmImage.setTag(position);
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(null);
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = (InputStream) new java.net.URL(urldisplay)
                    .getContent();

            mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null && (bmImage.getTag()).equals(this.position))
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

And how i populate my list view using JSON:

```
    class RetrieveFriendsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ArrayList<FriendsRowItem> FriendList = new ArrayList<FriendsRowItem>();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (pDialog != null) {

            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        // Showing progress dialog
        else {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Friends.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eposta", email));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sifre", pass));

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET, pairs);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                JSONObject obj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
                friends = obj.getJSONArray(TAG_EVENTS);
                for (int i = 0; i < friends.length(); i++) {
                    friend = new FriendsRowItem();
                    JSONObject c = friends.getJSONObject(i);
                    nick = c.optString("nick");
                    // friend.setTitle(c.optString("nick"));
                    img = c.optString("url_resim");
                    // friend.setImage(c.optString("url_resim"));
                    friend.setTitle(nick);
                    friend.setImage(img);
                    FriendList.add(friend);
                }

            } 
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        adapter = new FriendsListView(Friends.this, R.layout.list_item_3,
                FriendList);
        lvfriends.setAdapter(adapter);
        OnItemClickListener myListViewClicked = new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                FriendsRowItem name = (FriendsRowItem) parent
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(Friends.this, FriendsDisplay.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.putExtra("FriendName", name.toString());
                startActivity(i);

            }
        };
        lvfriends.setOnItemClickListener(myListViewClicked);
    }

}
```

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: what is the problem exactly? is that setting as planned in the second launch?

Comment: I actually found my problem after going through the code for the hundredth time, i changed my downloadImage constructor and onPostexecute to check each incoming bitmaps position.

Comment: Yes and edited my code. Wow i have come a long way in 5 years from here.